# Missing linux firmware (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, initramfs, firmware

When I ran `sudo apt upgrade` the last time, there appeared the following warnings:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_dmc_ver2_02.bin for module i915
```

Could you guide me on how to solve this problem

Comment: Unless you have one of those Intel CPU/GPU then not a problem. "W" means warning, not an error.

Comment: Please run: `sudo lshw | grep i915` Is that driver in use on your system? If not, ignore the warning.

Comment: @chili555 the output was configuration: driver=i915 latency=0. Does this mean the driver in use and I need to take care of the warning?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The needed files are present in the focal-updates, appropriate for Ubuntu 20.04, version of *linux-firmware*.

Please do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.187.20_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and check the message log:

```
sudo dmesg | grep i915
```

Is the warning resolved?

Comment: There's no warnings in the result. Thanks

Comment: Glad it's working! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it. https://askubuntu.com/tour